# How do I use multiple commands with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am having a problem using multiple jQuery commands.

My code:

```
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Left.gif"]').remove();
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Bottom.gif"]').remove();
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Right.gif"]').remove();
```

How do i separate these so they all work? Thanks.

Comment: If they all work individually, they should all work together like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search for all  td with backgrounds that start with "/images/PBox_Border_" you can do this:

```
$('td[background^="/images/PBox_Border_"]').remove();
```

You could also check to make sure it's a gif as well:

```
$('td[background^="/images/PBox_Border_"]')
   .filter('td[background$=".gif"]')
   .remove();
```

I just had to use a search like that, so just in case you need the info.

Answer (score 3):

Just seperate rules with comma.

```
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Left.gif"], td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Bottom.gif"], td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Right.gif"]').remove();
```

I suggest you should use them with combined version, it will work more faster than working the same method line by line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple selectors if you separate them by commas (all in the same string):

```
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Left.gif"], td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Bottom.gif"], td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Right.gif"]').remove();
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

There is also the `.add()` function:

```
$('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Left.gif"]').add('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Bottom.gif"]').add('td[background="/images/PBox_Border_Right.gif"]').remove();
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/add